# Why doesn't GHC recognize the function as linear?

Tags: haskell, linear-types

I have a very simple snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LinearTypes #-}

module Lib where

data Peer st = Peer { data :: String } deriving Show

data Idle
data Busy

sendToPeer :: Peer Idle %1-> Int -> IO (Peer Busy)
sendToPeer c n = case c of Peer d -> pure $ Peer d
```

I am on `resolver: ghc-9.0.1`.

From the [documentation](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/linear_types.html):

> A function f is linear if: when its result is consumed exactly once,
> then its argument is consumed exactly once. Intuitively, it means that
> in every branch of the definition of f, its argument x must be used
> exactly once. Which can be done by
>
> - Returning x unmodified
> - Passing x to a linear function
> - Pattern-matching on x and using each argument exactly once in the same fashion.
> - Calling it as a function and using the result exactly once in the same fashion.

and my function `sendToPeer` does exactly this - pattern-matches on `c` and its argument `d` is used once - in `Peer d` which is linear:

> By default, all fields in algebraic data types are linear (even if
> -XLinearTypes is not turned on).

but I got an error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘'Many’ with ‘'One’
        arising from multiplicity of ‘c’
• In an equation for ‘sendToPeer’:
          sendToPeer c n = case c of { Peer d -> pure $ Peer d }
   |
11 | sendToPeer c n =
   |            ^
```

Without `pure`:

```
sendToPeer :: Peer Idle %1-> Int -> Peer Busy
sendToPeer c n = case c of Peer d -> Peer d
```

but the error is the same.

Comment: Perhaps it thinks that `pure` is not linear?

Comment: I removed `pure` and not do return `Peer Busy`, not `IO (Peer Busy)` - the error is same

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are bumping up against multiple problems:

- `Prelude.pure` isn't linear.  You need to use the linear `Applicative` class and associated method function `pure` from `Control.Functor.Linear` in `linear-base`.
- `Prelude.IO` isn't linear (i.e., doesn't have an instance of the linear `Applicative` class).  You need to use the linear `IO` from `System.IO.Linear` in `linear-base`.
- *(In GHC versions older than 9.2)* `case` statements simply didn't work properly with the current `LinearTypes` extension.

With respect tot the last point, the GHC manual states:

> A `case` expression may consume its scrutinee `One` time, or `Many` times. But the inference is still experimental, and may over-eagerly guess that it ought to consume the scrutinee `Many` times.

The User's Guide for `linear-base` is blunter.  It includes a section titled [Case statements are not linear](https://github.com/tweag/linear-base/blob/master/docs/USER_GUIDE.md#case-statements-are-not-linear) which suggests that you just can't use them for linear functions.

For now, you have to avoid scrutinizing an expression with `case` if you want to retain it's `One`ness. On GHC version 9.2 or newer this workaround is no longer necessary.

The following appears to type-check.  I *think* I've got the imports set up in the recommended manner.  Note that there are versions of `pure` in both `Data.Functor.Linear` and `Control.Functor.Linear`, and they work differently.  See the comments at the top of the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-base-0.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Linear.html) for the `Data.Functor.Linear` module.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LinearTypes #-}

module Lib where

import Prelude.Linear
import Control.Functor.Linear as Control
import qualified Prelude as NonLinear
import qualified System.IO.Linear as Linear

data Peer st = Peer String deriving Show

data Idle
data Busy

sendToPeer :: Peer Idle %1-> Int -> Linear.IO (Peer Busy)
sendToPeer (Peer d) n = Control.pure (Peer d)
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `pure` from [Control.Functor.Linear](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-base-0.1.0/docs/Control-Functor-Linear.html#v:pure) instead, as well as the `IO` from [System.IO.Linear](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-base-0.1.0/docs/Prelude-Linear.html#t:IO), because contents of `Prelude` are simply not declared as linear.

Note that this even simpler example does not compile too:

```
sendToPeer :: Peer Idle %1-> IO (Peer Idle)
sendToPeer c = pure c
```

---

The issue for the "without `pure`" version looks quite suspicious to me and I think it's a bug, because it seems to work if the pattern matching is done at the argument level:

```
sendToPeer :: Peer Idle %1-> Int -> Peer Busy
sendToPeer (Peer d) n = Peer d
```

Comment: ` Could not find module ‘Control.Functor.Linear’`  Is it from linear-base?

Comment: Yes, `stack install linear-base` or the `cabal` equivalent. Remember to add it to the relevant config file in your project if you get errors about "hidden modules".

Comment: On my configuration it seems to conflict with `base`, so be prepared to choose a proper resolver

Comment: I removed `pure` at all from the shown code - the error is the same

Comment: also: `Unknown package: linear-base` on `stack install linear-base`.

Comment: Try one of these resolvers: https://www.stackage.org/package/linear-base/snapshots

Comment: I think the `case` thing is fixed in 9.2, but I'm not sure.

Comment: the same with `let` and `where` if I understand linearity rightly